# Importing a transparent image to flash

Tags: actionscript-3, transparency

How do I import an image that has transparent background to flash and give it class and use `addChild` to show it on the screen? Transparent background should stay transparent.

Answer (score 1):

This is answered on the main StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005068/better-way-to-include-images-in-as3-than-embed

In summation, you can either include your images in the swf and then call them from the code, or you can load external images. If you have the Flash authoring tool then one approach would be to import the image in the authoring tool, and then in the Library go into the Properties and set the ActionScript linkage for that image. If you don't have the Flash authoring tool then the equivalent approach is to use [Embed] tags at the top of your code.

If you can't or don't want to include the images in the swf (eg. loading user images) then use Loader

Comment: if i import the image background is not trasnparent and i need to import it that's the problem